# How to diminish CPU usage and avoid increasing fan speed?

Tags: power-management, cpu, fan

I have a LeNovo ideapad 330S.

Every time some program demands a bit more CPU usage, the fan goes wild.

In windows, I would go to the power saving options, and then I would decrease the percentage of maximum CPU usage to 70%, and the problem with the fan would be no more...

However, I'm not sure how to proceed in an analogous way in Ubuntu. I'm using the following:

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

In this OS, is there a way to limit the cpu usage? I'm not a tech savy person, so I have a preference for a visually friendly and simpler method.

Comment: This doesn't directly answering your question... but make sure that there isn't dust clogging up the fans. If there is, remove it and that should help significantly. See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/is-there-a-way-to-limit-overall-cpu-consumption)

Comment: Some people like to use [this Gnome extension](https://github.com/deinstapel/cpupower) to micromanage their processor power states. Note that you'll need to have an Intel processor that is supported by the `cpufreq` or `intel_pstate` scaling driver. Installation instructions can be found on the linked page and, if you already have one of the two drivers mentioned, you can install the extension [from the Gnome Extensions page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/).